# getting a list of running SKAction instances by key/name?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skaction

Is it possible to obtain the **keyName** (the `withKey` value) for a running action on a node?  Not interested in the `actionForKey`, that returns the action, I want the keyName (the string; let's assume it's random and I don't know it but want to find out what it's set to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in method in `SKNode` to retrieve all actions. Therefore, the best way is to keep a separate `NSArray` of action names. You'd add an action name to the list when the action is started and remove it, with help of the `completion:` argument.

Comment: Yea, thought of that already.  Was hoping for a built in solution.  :)  Ah, well.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. Just have a look at the members of `SKNode`.